# How to create variant without using smart controls in SAPUI5/ SAP FIORI

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am a newbie to SAP FIORI,

I have a requirement to create a variant for my custom filters(it's having some tree tables, checkboxes and radio buttons, a search field and input field and combo boxes and etc). Now I am using local storage concept to store the parameters of the selected filter to the browser and then retrieve them later.
Now I need to change them to a variant, but the problem is that as per my knowledge in FIORI, in order to create variant we need to use the smart controls like smart tables and smart filters and it requires some effort from oData side also for creating annotations. In my scenario, I am using sap.ui.table.treetable and sap.ui.table.table API's. Can I create some variant without changing my API's from sap.ui.table.table to smart table and if yes can someone share some code snippet of this.